# Find files containing specific words in a specified file and its subfolders and copy and paste them to a specified file

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a spreadsheet to speed up the none value added tasks we have for when a quote is converted to an order.  One of these process required the team to copy files from one folder into another folder for the projects team.  I have searched the web and found a few things on here, none of which give me exactly what i need and as i am new to this, combining them all is beyond my level at the moment.  Below is what i have so far with a description on what i would require.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In short, i would like to search a specified folder and its subfolders for any file that contains the words in its title such as "As Sold", "Contract" or "Class ID", i would then like it to copy these files to another specified folder.

**(1) Search for any files within a certain subfolders' structure where the Filenames contain As Sold for example. (2) Then when all the files are found, i wish to copy those files into another folder**

```
Sub sbCopyingAFile()

'Declare Variables
Dim FSO
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder As String

'This is Your File I want to copy, but i want the value to be any file that contains "as sold","Class ID" or_
'"Contract" in the file name. the "*As*Sold*" doesnt work at all, but if i write the exact file name it does work.
'I will have multiple files that say either of of the above so will need it to do all files
sFile = "*As*Sold*"

'Source folder, i would like this to look at the source folder and find any file as above in the specified folder
'and all subfolders, this only looks in that folder
sSFolder = "C:\Users\steven.byrne\Desktop\Test Folder 1\"

'Paste the all files into this folder
sDFolder = "C:\Users\steven.byrne\Desktop\Test Folder 2\"

'Create Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
    MsgBox "Specified File Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found"

'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
    FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder, True
    MsgBox "Specified File Copied Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
Else
    MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"
End If

End Sub
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciate, thank you :-)

Comment: Hi @StevenByrne, your question and need is not very clear. Could you tell what you wish to do or how we can help you please?

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina thank you for letting me know my question is not very clear, i have updated my question.  This is what i need help with: - In short, i would like to search a specified folder and its subfolders for any file that contains the words in its title such as "As Sold", "Contract" or "Class ID", i would then like it to copy these files to another specified folder.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok the `i would like to search a specified folder and its subfolders for any file that contains the words in its title such as "As Sold", "Contract" or "Class ID"` is clear.
But the `I would then like **it** to copy these files to another specified folder` isn't yet. What is this IT?

Comment: Sorry @TsiriniainaRakotonirina i meant copy them files, as in the files that contain those references.

Comment: You said though `search a specified folder` then then after you found them you wish now to `copy these files to another specified folder`. So first speak of **Folders** then you speak of **Files**, that why I was confused

Comment: ---> Do you mean `Search for the SubFolders` and `Copy-Paste those folders in another Folder`?

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina apologies, i did not mean to cause confusion. I wish to search a folder for files containing the references mentioned.  Once it has found all the files with those references i want it to copy those files and paste them into another specified file.

Comment: ---> Do you mean `Search for the SubFolders` and `Copy-Paste the *Content of those Folders* in another Folder`?

Comment: When it searches the folder, it needs to search all subfolders for those files, then copy and paste those files to another folder.

Comment: Ok, now it is clearer: (1) Search for any files within a certain subfolders' structure where the Filenames contain `As Sold` for example. (2) Then when all the files were found, you wish to `move` or `copy` those files into the folder?

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina yes that is correct, but `copy` not `move`.  Thank you for helping me make it clearer :-)

Comment: you're welcome. You can update your question with those explanation now while we work on the Script that will help you :)

Comment: I have now updated it, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was learning as well and successfully tested the following function that you can use to search within a subfolder and copy files into a giving destination.

But for it to work:

### Add FileSystemObject in your VBA Reference

For this to work, you need to :

1. Go to your VBE (Visual Studio Editor)
2. Open **References - VBAProject** from the menu `Tools\References`
3. When the following Dialog Box appears, search for **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** and **Tick/Check** it.

[image]

### The Search and Copy Subroutine:

```
'sFolderToSearch:= Location where you want to do the search (No "\" at the end)
'sFolderDestination:= Location where you want to found files to be copied (No "\" at the end)
'sListOfKeysToSearch:= a List of String containing key to search separated by sDelimiter (ex. "As Sold", "Contract" or "Class ID")
'sDelimiter:= It is the Delimiter you use to split your sListOfKeysToSearch
'             For Example:  sListOfKeysToSearch = "As Sold|Contract|Class ID", here by default the delimiter is "|".
Sub SearchAndCopy(sFolderToSearch As String, _
                    sFolderDestination As String, _
                    sListOfKeysToSearch As String, _
                    Optional sDelimiter As String = "|")

On Error GoTo CleanUp

Dim arrSearchKey() As String
Dim FSO As Object 'FileSystemObject
Dim foFolder As Folder
Dim foSubFolder As Folder
Dim fFile As file
Dim i As Long, nCopiedCnt As Long

    'Get the Folder List from sFolderToSearch
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set foFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sFolderToSearch)

    'Convert sListOfKeysToSearch to Array splitting it with the sDelimiter
    arrSearchKey = Split(sListOfKeysToSearch, sDelimiter)

    'nCopiedCnt is the Numbers of Files copied
    nCopiedCnt = 0

    With Application
        'Pause Screen update
        .ScreenUpdating = False

        'Change Cursor to Wait
        .Cursor = xlWait
    End With

    'Duration calculation
    'From here https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/1/28/vba-calculate-macro-run-time
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

    'Remember time when macro starts
    StartTime = Timer

    'Search all Subfolders within foFolder
    For Each foSubFolder In foFolder.SubFolders
        'Search all files within foSubFolder
        For Each fFile In foSubFolder.Files
            'Test if FileName is the same as each of the search Keys provided
             For i = LBound(arrSearchKey) To UBound(arrSearchKey)
                'If InStr is Positive then the Key is Found within the Filename
                If InStr(1, fFile.Name, arrSearchKey(i), vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
                    'Copy the file in the Destination Folder
                    FSO.CopyFile fFile.Path, _
                                sFolderDestination & "\" & fFile.Name, _
                                True                                'Set last Parameter to True if you want to overwite

                    'Increment nCopiedCnt
                    nCopiedCnt = nCopiedCnt + 1
                End If
             Next i
        Next fFile
    Next foSubFolder

    If nCopiedCnt = 0 Then
        'No file found with the search Keys
        MsgBox "No file found with the giving search keys!", vbInformation, "Search successful ..."
    Else
        'Determine how many seconds code took to run
        SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

        'Confirm how many files were copied
        MsgBox nCopiedCnt & " file(s) successfully Found and Copied in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation, "Search & Copy successful ..."
    End If

CleanUp:
    With Application
        'Restore Screen update
        .ScreenUpdating = True

        'Restore default Cursor
        .Cursor = xlDefault
    End With

    'Purge Memory
    Set FSO = Nothing
        Exit Sub

ErrorFound:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume CleanUp
End Sub
```

The Following notes are already in your Comment and are very important when you use the Subroutine:

- **sFolderToSearch:=** Location where you want to do the search (No "\" at
  the end)
- **sFolderDestination:=** Location where you want to found files
  to be copied (No "\" at the end)
- **sListOfKeysToSearch:=** a List of
  String containing key to search separated by sDelimiter (ex. "As
  Sold", "Contract" or "Class ID")
- **sDelimiter:=** It is the Delimiter you
  use to split your sListOfKeysToSearch
              For Example:  `sListOfKeysToSearch = "As Sold|Contract|Class ID"`, here by default the delimiter is "|".

### How to use it:

```
SearchAndCopy "Z:\Archive\My Search Folder","C:\New Folder\Destination","As Sold|Contract|Class ID","|"
'sFolderDestination should not have "\" at the end
'sFolderDestination should not have "\" at the end
'sListOfKeysToSearch is separated with "|" (whatever delimiter you use)
'sDelimiter is Optional. By Default it is "|"
```

I hope you would enjoy using it :)

All the Best!

Comment: Hello, i am struggling to get this to work or even run even though you have clear instructions.  I have never seen code in the brackets on a sub before.  What does that do `Sub SearchAndCopy(sFolderToSearch As String, _
                    sFolderDestination As String, _
                    sListOfKeysToSearch As String, _
                    Optional sDelimiter As String = "|")` ?

I added this in after that section
`sFolderToSearch = "C:\Users"
sFolderDestination = "C:\Users"
sListOfKeysToSearch = sDelimiter("As Sold", "Contract", "Class ID")
sDelimiter = ","`

Comment: #1. First of all have you been able to add from your Tools\Reference **FileSystemObject in your VBA Reference**? (I will be moving slowly so please reply to my questions one by one)

Comment: Thank you very much appreciated.  Yes I have done that. Thank you 

Comment: Hello, hope you are well, are you able to help any further, i have done your first step from 9th April.  Thank you,

Comment: Hello @Steven, could you refresh my mind please where you are still stack?

Comment: Hello @Tsiriniaina thank you for coming back to me, I could not get the code to work, as this is my first time doing something like this, you kindly offered to go through this with me step by step.  Your first step was on the April 9th and that was so i had done the FileSystemObject in my VBA. :) thank you again